# Why cron saves at /root, when should at /var/www?

Tags: linux, debian, cron, crontab, cronjob

Why my cron `*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/query/query.php &> /root/querylog.log` saves query.php output in the /root/ folder?

(this script shall save *.txt at its location)

`It should do so at /var/www`

Folder owner of `var/www/query/` is `web-data`.

Running it on Debian Squeeze 6.0

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the output of query.php? Maybe you should specify correct path of its output inside your php code?

Comment: What user is the cron running as?

Answer (score 3):

The `querylog.log` file is saved in the `/root` directory because that's exactly where you have specified it should be saved.

If you want to change its location, just edit the path to your desired location, e.g. `/var/www/querylog.log`.

Comment: saves query.php output is 2 *.txt files. When fired at my local machine they are created at the same dir as the query.php. But cron saves 'em there, where log is saved - why? (output and log fire are 2 separate things btw)

Comment: I think he is not talking about .log file but rather output of query.php, log goes in root as he wants it to do.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the cron job it is run as root user, so it is executed at the root user's $HOME, i.e. `/root`.

If you want the cron job to run in another location, so that the output is generated there, you should move there first eg writting a script which does everything and runnig it from cron:

my_query.bash

```
cd /var/www
/var/www/query/query.php &> /root/querylog.log
```

And the cron line becomes

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /path/to/script/my_query.bash
```

Comment: I don't understand the down votes for this answer: it seems to be saying exactly what happens (query.php saves output to directory it is run from, cron runs it as root, so script runs in .roo